# Visual Studio 2010. Saving Multiline textbox in my sql

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

Can anyone give me an idea on how to save the datas that are typed into a textbox (multiline) in vb.net 2010 to my database (mysql)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a String-representation of your Object and store this String to your database. JSON might be useful for you here, [JSON.net](https://json.codeplex.com/) is commonly used...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to insert a record in a mysql database:

Let's say you have a mysql database called (myDB) and a table called (myTable).
There are two fields in myTable: ID(int) and TextBoxData(Text)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
Sub connect()
Dim DatabaseName As String = "myDB"
Dim server As String = "ip address here"
Dim userName As String = "username here"
Dim password As String = "password here"
If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName,    password, DatabaseName)
Try
conn.Open()

MsgBox("Connected")
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
conn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

' The following code is used to write to MySQL database:
    Try
    conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception

```
End Try

Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO `myTable` (`ID` , `TextBoxData`) VALUES ('{0}' , '{1}')", "", TextBox1.Text))
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()
```

Source: [VB.NET connect to MySql Server](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/Tutorials/MsCodes/code8.htm)